# How to confirm an OS pop up is present in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where a click triggers an OS pop up, my need is to click and wait until the OS pop up is present before going ahead (at times the pop up is delayed and rest of code triggers and following cases fails)
Is there a way to confirm or wait until the OS pop up is present after the click ? Thank you in advance.

Tried below but could not make it happen,

1. if  an element is clickable while OS pop up is present, expecting it to be false as the control is on the pop up but received true.
2. getWindowhandles (though am aware it only gets browser handles)

Comment: You only have access to the browser with Selenium, nothing else. You'll need additional software to work with non-browser entities such as OS popups.